# Cramping in chest after working out

Tags: muscle-soreness

Sometimes 1/2 day to a day after a tough workout, when I lean forward, I get a severe cramping in my chest...it feels like a bad muscle cramp in my ribs (just above the sternum on the right hand side).  What is my body trying to tell  me? and how can I stretch to stop this from happening?

Comment: What type of training? Does this type of cramping happen consistently each time you train?  If so, have you consulted a doctor?

Comment: Weight lifting - mostly after squats or dead lifts.  No, I'm not into doctors

Comment: Performing squats or dead lifts should not cause cramping in your chest.  If done correctly, they affect your lower body.  What is your experience level?

Comment: I've been following the 5/3/1 program with great improvement to all my lifts...I've had this pain on/off for maybe 3-4 months.  Feels like a muscle cramp more than anything else, I would have said hernia, but it feels to high up for that

Comment: I'll reiterate.  That type of muscle response from squats or dead lifts is unusual.  For pain that's consistently lasted 3 to 4 months, you may want to visit your doc.  Failure to do so may lead to a chronic condition and a long layoff from training.  Train smart....

Comment: Sorry, the 3-4 months is the time I've had pains - the pain/cramping usually lasts for only a few days - and has happened 2-3 times over the last 3-4 months.

Comment: Have you tried popping your sternum when you have this pain @

Comment: Popping my sternum? no

Comment: honestly, I would suggest getting it checked with a Doctor.  If may well, just be cramps, but it's not worth leaving.  They will probably do ECG, stick pads on chest to monitor your heart and maybe an X-ray.   Very simple and not painful at all. Go for peace of mind

Answer (score 1):

It clearly is a sign that your upper body is not in par with your lower, which means that over time you have become accustomed to work out heavily for your lower body but not the upper body.

The solution to this is very easy. Start focusing on upper body workouts, preferably bench presses (and all its variations) and also incorporate exercises that work your core such as planks, abs and back extensions.

Perform dynamic stretches when possible and start using a foam roller.

Oh and also stay well hydrated, and of course enjoy your workouts!

Answer (score 0):

Cramping is usually caused by dehydration.  For me the first muscle that always cramps is my LATs.  When this happens I know it is time to drink more water.

Your body is most likely dehydrated.  Drink more water.  Stretching is a short term fixed to cramping.

Comment: -1. There is no proven correlation between dehydration and cramping, or electrolytes and cramping, or [insert cause here] and cramping. Cramping is still a mystery with many theories and no proofs.